# How to extract 4 digit number after a certain word using Regex in java?

Tags: java, regex

I want to extract all the company ids, which will always be **4** digits.

Here is my String:

```
String test= "{\"company_id\":2567\"IDNUmber=8847,school:Seen\"company_id\":2576"}";
```

I want to extract only the 4 digits after the company_id part. In the String above the values would be **2567** , **2576** and the **8847** I want to ignore because it does not come after company_id\

This is what I have so far:

```
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\b\\d{4}\\b)");
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
```

The problem with this regex is that it will extract any four digits.

Comment: there are several ways to solve this.  But if your string is in JSON format, then the solution will be the cleanest.

Comment: That line with the `test` string does not compile, since the end-brace (`}`) is outside the string literal.

Comment: @Andreas is right. The intended code is probably `String test = "{\"company_id\":2567\"IDNUmber=8847,school:Seen\"company_id\":2576\"}";`

Answer (score 4):

You can use

> "company_id\\\\\":(\\d{4})"

As your regex pattern which has the following breakdown:

- **company_id** - matches the characters company_id literally (case sensitive)
- **\\\\** - matches the character \ literally to get the \ after company_id, you need 4 of these because you need to escape the escape . First escape to escape the string treatment of \ as special character, and 2nd escape for regular expression treatment of \ as special character.
- **\":** - matches the characters ": literally, with " being escaped by the \
- **(\\d{4})** - captures the 4 digits that you want

Comment: Could you please provide a demo?

Comment: There are no  \  in the input. Assuming the `}` was supposed to be inside the string literal, the actual value is `{"company_id":2567"IDNUmber=8847,school:Seen"company_id":2576}`.

Comment: Thank you for for the answer and explanation. Let's say that I want to check that the company name is like this  {\company_id . How would I have to change the regex you provided? I should have asked this in the question sorry

Answer (score 2):

```
"(?<=company_id\":)\\d{4}"
```

Will extract the pattern according to the specifications and examples you provided, clean of clutter text (gives just the ID numbers).

Comment: This is not returning anything.

Comment: @danilo Strange, it works for me...I'll add an [mcve] link so you can test and confirm your environment; and compare the codes.

Comment: Here is the link to the MCVE gist: https://gist.github.com/AlmightyR/dfa4c4d256d84fff6402

Comment: My bad. It does work. I forgot to ask on the question. I want  to check the name  has all the characters (including brackets)  {\"company_id\":2567\  before getting the number. How would I have to change the regex you provided above. Thank you

Comment: @danilo I recommend that you read through the [Java's Pattern Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html); as your doubts seem to be related to not knowing the Java's regex syntax more than anything else. --- As for the brackets, I think a pure regex solution is not possible in that case. You will need to confirm the presence of the brackets first, with a "second" (first) regex, or with parsing; and then get the multiple `company_id` instances within using a second regex (the one I provided, or someone else's, depending on what you want to do).

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work in your case, since the ID's are coupled with ":" and the others with "=" :

```
:(\\d*)
```

or

```
:(\\d{4})
```

---

Attention : First one will work with any length number after a **":"**

---

### Code

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(":(\\d*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("{\"company_id\":2567\"IDNUmber=8847,school:Seen\"company_id\":2576\"}");

while (m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

### Output

```
2567

2576
```

Comment: I intend no offence to you or your skills, Yassin, but this doesn't take into account that the use-case provided by the OP is just an example, and that there might be other undisclosed structures that use `:` followed by numbers, which would cause false-positives. It also displays a bad principle of `Maintainability` and `Extensibility`, as, even if such structure doesn't exist now, it's possible inclusion in the future would make this code cause said false-positives. --- With that said, the OP doesn't specify anything that would make this solution invalid either, so I won't down-vote,

Comment: @TheLima I was actually thinking the same and was hesitating. Ive already deleted posts when knowing it must. But here, I do not have this feel. Thanks for the attention though. PS : Im onl'y a beginner in regex so my skills are not offended in any way lol.